# PHP form not sending string variables

Tags: php

I am trying to complete an online payment system. The final stage is sending the PHP form off to the payment provider where the user pays and upon completion is redirected back to another page where I can use variables set up from the original PHP form page to populate the response page.

```
$formname=$_POST['s00_form_name']; #contains "My Project Page"
form method="POST" action="https://hpp.......">
<input type="hidden" name="COMMENT1" value=<?=$formname?>>
```

The only text that comes back is "My"

or

```
$formname="My Project Page"; 
form method="POST" action="https://hpp.......">
<input type="hidden" name="COMMENT1" value=<?=$formname?>>
```

The only text that comes back is again "My"

But if I just add the text to the form

```
<input type="hidden" name="COMMENT1" value="My Project Page">
```

The text coming back is "My Project Page"

But the latter is not very useful.
Any idea why a variable, that I echo onto the page prior to sending, only sends one word (this has been confirmed by the payment provider.

I do have a workround which is adding "_" (My_Projext..." and then removing them on the reponse page but some of this text is stored like this in thier  database so I would rather avoid this also if possible.

Thanks in advance.
VanNuys

Comment: You need quotes. Otherwise it's just `<input type="hidden" name="COMMENT1" value=My Project Page>` - see the issue?

Comment: If that suggestion doesn't fix it, please post a [mcve].  You got lucky in that your problem was relatively obvious this time.

Comment: Yes Niet the Dark Absol  really makes sense - thank you.

Answer (score 3):

It's because of quotes issue while assigning the value to the hidden input field. Please try the below code

```
$formname="My Project Page"; 
form method="POST" action="https://hpp.......">
<input type="hidden" name="COMMENT1" value="<?= $formname ?>">
```

Comment: Thank you everyone who replied. Yes I can see now what my problem was.

Comment: Sorry pressed enter by mistake - thank you very much. What confused me was all the other variables (that only contained a single value) used the non-quote version so I just copied that. Many thanks once again

Comment: @user1777582 nop :) glad my answer resolved your problem. Thanks

Comment: Please mark this as the answer. This way, @ManikandanS gets an little reputation reward ;)

Comment: @KoenHollander ha ha. true :)

Comment: @Koen Hollander Sorry if I seem a bit thick but how do you mark this as the answer? I'm new to Stackoverflow

Comment: @user1777582 Sorry, there was some confusion. anyway in your question you posted with only one hidden element also you didn't mention anything about other input elements in your question. so still you are facing the problem with the hidden element field values while posting the form?

Comment: @Manikandan S All problems refering to the hidden elements have been fixed. I only included the one element as this was the one I was having trouble with and I guessed it was a simple syntax issue but I had no idea what  it was - obvious now. Please consider this now resolved. Thank you.

Comment: @user1777582 ok :)